# Retrieve data from *ngForm and push to firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I have signup form for new users. I want to push the new user details to firebase database.Can anyone please help me with it.

```html
        <div class="column" style="padding: 7.5%" >
            <form >
        <label> Full Name </label>
        <input type="text" ng-maxlength="10" hint="Full Name"   class="form-control">
        <label> Phone Number </label>
        <input type="text" hint="phone" id="phone" maxlength="10" minlength="10"  class="form-control">
        
        <label> Aadhar Number </label>
        <input type="text" hint="aadhar" id="aadhar" maxlength="16"  minlength="16" class="form-control">
        <br><br>
        <button id="signup" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="../../home/dashboard">Signup</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user service like this:

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { IUser } from './IUser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {


  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  createUser(user: IUser) {
    return this.db.collection('users').add(user);
  }

  getAllUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.collection('users').snapshotChanges();
  }

  getUserById(id) {
    return this.db.doc('users/' + id).get();
  }


  deleteUser(id) {
    return this.db.collection("users").doc(id).delete();
  }

  updateUser(id, user: IUser) {
    return this.db.collection("users").doc(id).set(user);
  }

}
```

and call `createUser()` from your component onSubmit:

component.ts

```
onSubmit(): void {
  this.service.createUser(this.userForm.value).then(
    res => {
    }
  )
}
```

component.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: in component.ts 
 onSubmit(): void {
    this.service.createUser(this.userForm.value).then(
      res => {
      }
    )
  }

For the above snippet..I have declared 
 userForm: any;
  service: any;

But I am getting an error while using "res"
error"- res' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: You can just use it like var res - res

Comment: That didn't work :/ ..I tried declaring  it as var res=res;

Comment: onSubmit(): void {
    this.service.createUser(this.userForm.value).then(
      (      _res: any) => {
      }
    )
  }

I tried this....but the project wouldn't load

Comment: Can you create a stackbiltz of your project

Comment: I just tried passing the data in a different manner and that worked. Thanks for the help :) . I'll posting my solution soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202187/discussion-between-adrita-sharma-and-akhilesh-pothuri).

Answer (score 0):

The following method helped me rectify the issue :

user.service.ts

```js
 createUser(data: any) {
    this.users.push(data);
  }
```

This is the login.ts file:

```js
instituteLogins(instaForm: NgForm){
    console.log("Entered new patient");
    
    console.log(instaForm.value);
    this.addUser(instaForm.value['phoneno'],instaForm.value["patient"],instaForm.value['aadhar']);
    
  }
  
  
  addUser(uid: string, name: string, mobile: string){
    var user = new User();
    user.uid = uid;
    user.name = name;
    user.mobile = mobile;
    this.userService.createUser(user);
  }
```